# Db2 find occurance in a string

Tags: db2, db2-400

In db2 ,need to find a word can present or not in a sentence.
Either 1 or 0.
Present means 1
Not means 0

Need a solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried to search the corresponding function in the [IBM i](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i) product documentation for your IBM i version?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like this

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN sentence LIKE '%word%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as present
FROM
    some_table
```

or better

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(sentence,'\bword\b') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as present
FROM
    some_table
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm

> `\b` Match if the current position is a word boundary. Boundaries occur at the transitions between word (\w) and non-word (\W) characters, with combining marks ignored.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm#rbafzregexp_like__regexp_likecontrol